# CSS Menu Help (Second menu dissapear)

Tags: css, menu

I am trying to put this css menu together but I couldn`t get it working right. When you go over any link in top menu it opens up second menu although second menu disappears when you go on it. Plus, its misplaced. I couldn't place it in left:0

http://tinyurl.com/7rxskdj

```css
#menu {width:800px;background-color:#FFF;min-height:30px;border:0;border-top:2px solid #8BD2E4;padding:0 5px;margin:0 auto;}
#nmenu {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;width:700px;}
#nmenu li {display:inline;float:left;height:20px;margin-left:45px;position:relative;}
#nmenu li.frst {margin-left:0}
#nmenu li a {font: 11px/30px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;text-decoration:none;color:#979598;letter-spacing:2px;font-weight:bold;text-transform:uppercase;}
#smedia {width:100px;height:30px;float:left;}
#fb, #tw, #pt {background: #FFF url(smedia.png) no-repeat center;width:16px;height:16px;display:block;float:right;margin:7px 3px;}
#fb {background-position: -1px -1px;}
#tw {background-position: -18px -1px;}
#pt {background-position: -35px -1px;}
#nmenu li ul {display:none;position:absolute;top:30px;left:0;border:1px solid red;background-color:#FFF;}
#nmenu li:hover ul {display:block}
#nmenu li ul li {float:left;width:100px;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the below css:

```
#nmenu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 44px;
    position: relative;
}

#nmenu li ul {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
    left: -5px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}

#nmenu li a {
    color: #979598;
    display: block;
    font: bold 11px/30px Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix the disappearing menu: Add 5px bottom padding to your top level anchors which will remove the gap between elements.

The 'misplaced' problem is due to the default padding and margins on the `ul` and `li` elements. Explicitly set the margins and padding to position them.

Answer (score 1):

You're applying a height to your list item instead of your link item inside your `li`, so move the height and also apply a line-height to your `a` tags that matches the height of your menu block and then you can simply reposition your submenu to appear exactly 100% from your menu item, like so:

**CSS**

```
#nmenu li a {
   height:30px;
   line-height:30px;
   display:block;
}

#nmenu li ul {
   top:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute positioning leaves a gap between the container `<li>` and the `<ul>` child element. Decrease the value for "top" on `#nmmenu li ul {}`.